# Positioning elements within fieldset

Tags: html, css

I have made a custom `fieldset` and it works well only in Chrome. How I can solve this problem?

It must be label with input text in right part of field and label with input text in right part of field, but in 1 row below.

Here is the CSS:

```
#field {
    width: 300px;
}
.name {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.email {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<fieldset id = "field">
    <legend>Add a wish</legend>
    <input id = "name" class = "name" type = "text" width = "100"/>
    <label for = "name" class = "name">Nam::</label>
    <input id = "email" class = "email" type = "text" width = "100"/>               
    <label for = "email" class = "email">Email:</label>
    <label id = "wis">Wish</label>
    <textarea cols = "25" rows = "3" id = "wishes"></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please show your html code

Comment: @Andrii explain a bit more

Comment: is this what u need http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleit/NUC8S/1/

Comment: Yes it is, but it is such showing only in chrome browser, but in another browsers it is showing differently. And I don't know how solve this problem